# NFT Hydroponics for Lettuce

Tags: hydroponic, lettuce

I am looking at building a small NFT system to test the viability of growing lettuce commercially for local consumption.

Investigating options for NFT. Right now I am looking at using 3"-4" PVC or ABS pipes.

When I was checking prices on these materials, I noticed a 4" x 2" eaves trough made of PVC. The flat bottom would be better suited to an NFT system, but I am not sure if this will be deep enough to grow the lettuce properly.

I am looking at growing Romaine and Butterleaf mostly (Though this may change).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I am looking to find out if a 4" x 2" trough would be deep enough to grow the lettuce varieties mentioned.

Comment: I went to my local hydro shop yesterday and this will be more than suitable for growing lettuce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We provide commercial hydroponic systems and the channels that we use are made from virgin HDPE and are 2" X 4".  The 2" depth is perfect for romaine and butterhead.  They don't fall over and will grow from seed to harvest in about 6 weeks.  Go to the American Hydroponics website to see the full line of commercial hydro equipment.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Should things go well with the DIY system, I will be looking at moving into a commercial system.

Answer (score 1):

I went to my local hydro shop yesterday and this will be more than suitable for growing lettuce.

Comment: can you inform us a bit about what they suggested? as it is now this answer is neither informative nor helpful to those that may come looking for the answer to this same question later

Comment: Since my question was "Is a 4x2" trough suitable for growing lettuce?" this answer is very informative and helpful to those looking for the same answer, which is YES.